Hot water pex line to shower valve does not have any water pressure
One of the bathrooms in the house I moved into does not get any hot water in the shower. Hot water available in all other bathrooms and in the sink of the bathroom with the problem. I removed the shower mixer valve and see no problems other than hot water pex line having no water coming out.
The central pex manifold labeled for this bathroom has its valves open. Closing the cold line shuts off cold water to the shower, but hot water seems to be not coming. Lines above and below this one on the manifold work fine. Only the hot line in question either does not have water or isn’t connected to the shower. All hot water lines on the manifold are open.
How can I tell if a pex line at the manifold is the one connected to the shower on the other end?
Or alternatively, is there a way to tell if a pex line has water pressure or not without opening the connectors
Or any other thoughts on how to diagnose what is wrong with the hot water pex line?

"How can I tell if a pex line at the manifold is the one connected to the shower on the other end?" By process of elimination. Shut down each valve in the manifold one at a time. Label each shutoff and bathroom faucet as the water is turned off. The shutoff that doesn't turn off the water at any of the faucets is the one to the shower. Since you're only working with 'red' lines it should be simple.

"I removed the shower mixer valve and see no problems other than hot water pex line having no water coming out."  Assuming you did as you stated and disconnected the hot water from the valve and no water came out, says that the problem is no hot water to the shower mixing valve.   Find the shut off for that hot line and see if you have water there.  Maybe the valve is defective.

Thank you for the suggestions. I tried process of elimination but failed to find the other end. I think the lines might be connected to mutiple fixtures. I need to turn off multiple manifold valves to fully stop water at some fixtures. All hot water lines at manifold became warm, so there is clearly water at the manifold end and is flowing somewhere. I did not disconnect the hot water line to the problem shower valve because I do not have experience with pex and worry that I might not be able to reinstall without having to break open the shower wall.

I did remove the cartridge and opened the hot stop valve and no water came out. I suppose the stop valve could be clogged even though the screw bolt is turning. Is there a way to tell if there is water in the hot line without disconnecting the pex line from the valve?
